# Twilio: is it possible to finish the <Dial> verb before timeout?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We have an app that uses Twilio (with TwiML), and we'd like to implement the following logic:

- an incoming Call is being directed to multiple Users
- if all of them ignores the Call, it should be routed to the pre-defined phone number

TwiML we return at the Call start:

```
<Dial callerId="{incomingNumber}" action="{callbackUrl}" timeout="30">
  <Client statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallback="{statusCallbackUrl}">
    <Identity>{userId1}</Identity>
  </Client>
  <Client statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallback="{statusCallbackUrl}">
    <Identity>{userId2}</Identity>
  </Client>
</Dial>
```

If this `<Dial>` wasn't answered in 30 seconds, it goes to our `callbackUrl`, which returns the following:

```
<Dial callerId="{incomingNumber}" action="{callbackUrl}" timeout="30">
  <Number>{phoneNumber}</Number>
</Dial>
```

And it works as it should, but my question is - can we finish the first `<Dial>` before the timeout if both Users ignored the Call (using `call.ignore()` from Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK).

We also can keep track of who received a Call, and who clicked `ignore`, but I still don't know if there's a way to finish the current `<Dial>` before the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the way to do that:

- I should simply use `call.reject()` instead of `call.ignore()`
- rejecting doesn't mean it'll stop ringing for others
- when all the Users reject the Call - the `<Dial>` will be finished with the `busy` status, and it'll trigger `callbackUrl`